# Passing custom values in url when authorizing twitter and facebook

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

When I have a user authorize to use my app for Facebook and Twitter using their API, how can I pass Facebook and Twitter custom variables so that if the user does authorize their account to use my Facebook and Twitter app the callback URL will contain the custom data I need on my side? I'm using the PHP API class for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out for Twitter. Using the latest SDK:

```
twitterObj->getAuthenticateUrl(null,array(
                                    'oauth_callback' => '{customcallbackurlhere}'
                                    )
);
```

---

Ok, it looks like I found it for Facebook too:

```
    $params = array(
        'fbconnect'=>0,
        'canvas'=>0,
        'scope'=>'{permissionshere}',
        'redirect_uri' => '{callbackurlhere}'       
    );

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```